# Setting limit to record entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**I have the following:**

```
after_action :prevent_order_create, :only => [:update, :create]
...
private

def prevent_order_create
      @order = Order.find(params[:id]) #line 270
      @listing = Order.find_by(params[:listing_id])

      @order_seller = @order.where(order_status: [1]).where(:seller)

      if @order_seller.count >= 0
        @listing.update_column(:listing_status, 3)
      end

end
```

The **goal** is to limit the amount of orders that can be open for any 1 seller.

When I use this code, I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Order without an ID):

app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:270:in `prevent_order_create'
```

The order gets created but for whatever reason this issue is happening.  Shouldn't the method be getting checked AFTER the order is made without issues?

btw using `0` for testing purposes.

EDIT:

I did:

```
def prevent_order_create
  @order_seller = Order.where(order_status: [1]).where(listing_id: Listing.ids)

  if @order_seller.count >= 10
    @listing.update_column(:listing_status, 3)
  end

end
```

Seems to work for now.  Will update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you describe is as expected.

An after action is run after the action is already executed, so the record has already been persisted to your DB by the time the exception happens.

The exception is caused because `params[:id]` is `nil`, which makes sense for a create action.

#### Update after clarification in comment

OP said:

> I want after create and update... to find any orders with matching `:listing_id`'s and with `order_status`'s of [1] to then count those records. If the count is >= 1000, to then change the listing_status of the Listing

I think the way I would do this is in an `after_save` in the `Order` model.  Based on your latest edit something like:

```
scope :status_one, -> { where order_status: 1 }  # I'm guessing this should be 1 not [1] as you keep putting
after_save :update_listing

def update_listing
  if listing.orders.status_one.count >= 10
    listing.update! listing_status: 3
  end
end
```

So that's basically saying that if the associated listing has 10 or more associated orders with order_status=1 then set its status to 3.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that [`find(params[:id])`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) raises a *RecordNotFound* exception if no records can be found. If the intent is to use `nil` instead you should use [`find_by(id: params[:id])`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) this doesn't raise an exception and returns `nil` if no record can be found.

Comment: Oh i see now. I should be doing something more along the lines of @order = Order.where(:listing_id.match) ?

Comment: Anything that results in `@order`, `@listing` or `@order_listing` being `nil` is going to result in an exception.  It's not clear how you can ever achieve the goal you stated in an `after_action` nor with the code you're showing.

Comment: I want after create and update... to find any orders with matching `:listing_id`'s and with `order_status`'s of [1] to then count those records.  If the count is >= 1000, to then change the listing_status of the Listing.

Comment: tbh there are multiple things wrong with the code sample provided. 1) `@listing = Order.find_by(params[:listing_id])` The params of `find_by` should not be a single value, but an attribute/value pair (`find_by(listing_id: params[:listing_id])` which is a guess). 2) `@order_seller = @order.where(order_status: [1]).where(:seller)` this line has 2 faults. You call `.where(order_status: [1])` on an instance of `Order` which most likely raises an "no method error". `.where(:seller)` here you try to query for a value without specifying the attribute, *what attribute should be "seller"?*

Comment: I made an update to my OP... might have it working but will continue to test.  Wanted to get the code on here

Comment: Thanks that also works as well and probably is faster than the one i created.

Comment: To clarify... `after_save` triggers on updates as well?